# Azure Functions GET /metadata/instance Cancelled Calls

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, timer-trigger

We are running a number of Azure Functions on a `Linux Consumption Plan` instance using `v4` functions written in `C#`. Code is deployed using `GitHub Actions` and all use `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk Version 1.14.1`.

One of the functions uses a `CosmosDB Change Trigger` to activate, and another is using a `Timer Trigger` set to execute very five minutes.

Our Application Insights for the functions is showing `GET: {ipAddress}/metadata/instance` calls every five minutes, each with an average duration of 1.1 minutes, and always resulting in a `Cancelled` state.

Where and why are these calls being made, and what can be done to avoid this? It seems like this would be adding unnecessary overhead load to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call is made by the Azure Cosmos DB SDK to capture Azure VM metadata information. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows

This call is made **during client initialization** and the failure is not critical for the Cosmos DB client. The purpose is, for cases where you have issues and telemetry is emitted, it adds information such as, where is the location of the Azure VM and helps to identify cases where you have multiple client instances.

The important part here is, this should happen only **during client initialization**. The CosmosDBTrigger creates the client once and reuses it, if you are seeing it every 5 minutes, this means that either:

- You are using Azure Functions Consumption Plan, and after a period of inactivity, the Functions runtime is killing the function. So whenever there are new changes, the runtime starts again, so a new client needs to be created. Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/
- If you are not using Consumption Plan, then it is possible your code in your project is using `CosmosClient` to perform some operations on an Azure Cosmos DB container and you are not following the Singleton pattern (for example, creating a new CosmosClient on your TimerTrigger for every execution). This is an anti-pattern. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients. If this is your case, I'd advice to look into this example project that leverages Azure Functions Dependency Injection to generate a Singleton CosmosClient: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions

Comment: We are, in fact, using Azure Functions Consumption Plan, which explains why the client is being created each time. We are, in fact, using the proposed Singleton pattern using DI for CosmosClient, but the fact that we are using a Consumption Plan explains why it's being initialized every 5 minutes. 
Any idea why the call is failing each time? And, more importantly, taking over 1.1 minutes to fail?

Comment: Failing each time might mean that Azure Functions, when on Consumption Plan, does not allow this call. This API is an Azure level API, might not be supported in all compute platforms. Why it takes 1.1 min, no idea though, maybe because the HTTP connections are warming up.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it must be a Consumption Plan specific issue. The fact that the failure is not critical is enough to let me sleep at night! :-) Thank you.